# Is there many statements of the universal coefficient theorem?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I have been using the following statement of the UCT:

$$H_{i}(C;G) \cong H_{i}(C) \otimes G \oplus \operatorname{Tor}(H_{i-1}(C),G).$$

But now I want to calculate the cohomology ring of a certain map and I know its homology groups, is there a statement of UCT that help me in calculating the cohomology groups knowing the homology groups? and how this form is related to the form of UCT I mentioned above?

Comment: What do you mean by the cohomology ring of a map?

Comment: In any case, it sounds like you might be looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem#Universal_coefficient_theorem_for_cohomology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an abelian group $G$ and a chain complex $(C_\bullet, \partial_\bullet)$, the universal coefficient theorem for cohomology is given by the short exact sequence

$$0\to \operatorname{Ext}(H_{n-1}(C),G) \to H^n(C_n,G) \to \operatorname{Hom}(H_n(C),G)\to 0$$ where $H_*(C)$ is homology with integral coefficients, i.e. $$H_*(C) = H_*(C,\mathbb{Z})$$

The upshot of this is that it allows you to compute cohomology with coefficients in $G$ purely from homology with integral coefficients.

Note that obviously your homology and cohomology are dual exactly if $\operatorname{Ext}  (H_{n-1}(C),G)$ vanishes, which is precisely the case whenever $H_{n-1}(C)$ is free abelian.

Therefore, if your homology group $H_{n-1}(C)$ happens to be free abelian, you have

$$H^n(C_n,G) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(H_n(C),G).$$

Comment: The short exact sequence also splits which is what allows for the calculation of the isomorphism type of the group.

Comment: So in your fifth line do you mean $H_{*}(C) = H^{*}(C, \mathbb Z)$?

Comment: In the line before last , for me $H_{n-1}(C)$ is called homology group, why are you calling it cohomology group?

Comment: @Smart20 that was a typo. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Smart20 No, $H_*(C) = H_*(C,\mathbb{Z})$ means that the homology term $H_*(C)$ without mentioning the coefficients is in fact homology with integral coefficients $H_*(C,\mathbb{Z})$. We could therefore also have written the short exact sequence with integral coefficient terms $H_*(C,\mathbb{Z})$ but it's often more convenient to omit the coefficients if it's known that  $H_*(C) = H_*(C,\mathbb{Z})$